# Download webpage source from a page that requires authentication

Tags: linux, shell, http, curl, wget

I would like to download a webpage source code from a page that requires authentication, using shell script or something similar (like Perl, Python, etc..) in a Linux machine.

I tried to use wget and curl, but when I pass the URL, the source code that is being downloaded is for a page that ask me for credential. The same page is already open on Firefox, or Chrome, but I don't known how I can re-use this session.

Basically what I need to do is run a refresh on this page in a regular basis, and grep for some information inside the source code. If I found what I'm looking for, I will trigger another script.

-- Edit --

Tks @Alexufo .I managed to make it work, this way:

1 - Download a Firefox addon to allow me save the cookies in a TXT file. I used this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/

2 - Logged in the site I want, and saved the cookie.

3 - Using wget:

```
wget --load-cookies=cookie.txt 'http://my.url.com' -O output_file.txt
```

4 - Now the page source code is inside output_file.txt and I can parse the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURL should works anywhere.

1) do first response for autorization. Save cookes.
2) use cookes when you try second response to get you source page code.

update:
Wget should work with post autorization like curl
[wget with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)
update2: http://www.httrack.com/

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize (http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) can do that. I am using it (together) with Ruby 2.0.0 for exactly that.